# Comparing std::addressof() with hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, comparison, hex

How I can make the following code to work?

```
for (auto f=face.begin(); f!=face.end(); ++f)
{
    if (std::addressof(*f) == 0x18b9160) // error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
    {
        cout << "found";
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the comparison useful (assuming you get it to compile)?

Comment: @Praetorian: This is needed to debug my code.

Comment: Simply use a cast then: `if ((void*)std::addressof(*f) == (void*)0x18b9160)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (std::addressof(*f) == (void*)0x18b9160)
```