# reference_wrapper does not change addresses accordingly

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, memory-address, reference-wrapper

This question is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346445/getting-different-address-every-time) question. I understand that due to `push_back()` new memory allocation takes place and the address of the first element of `std::vector v` changes but should not `std::vector v2` change its address accordingly?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v2;

    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        int b = i;

        v.push_back(b);
        v2.push_back(v.back());

        std::cout << "org: " << std::addressof(v[0]) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ref: " << std::addressof(v2[0].get()) << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
org: 0x605010
ref: 0x605030
org: 0x605050
ref: 0x605010
org: 0x605030
ref: 0x605070
```

Comment: References are invalidated when a vector resizes, so your program has undefined behaviour (when you call `get()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the reference_wrapper is like a pointer. When the first vector reallocates, the old int object in memory is destroyed, and the int pointed to by the reference_wrapper is invalid. It is an error to use it now.